# Prevent user from changing url parameters?

Tags: javascript, url, encryption, parameters

Is there a way to prevent user from changing url parameters?
I have a vuejs app and an api server and I need to generate urls with a custom price in it and prevent the user from modifying this price.

I have tried to encrypt this price with an encryption algorithm but storing a secret key in my client code is not very secured.

Is there a better solution than encryption to do this sort of thing, I don't know much about these questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can't prevent users to write what ever they want on the addressbar of their own browser. Store the prices on your server only, and send some ids to the client instead of prices.

Comment: No, you can't prevent users from changing the URL or query parameters. If you don't want a user messing about with the parameters, try putting it in the body. Body parameters in a POST request for example.

Comment: A user can interfere the AJAX call/form submission, and change the values anyway. The only way is to just keep everything important on the server only. If you want to show the prices on a page, include them in the HTML when the page is created. When you're going to regocnize a user-selected product, use an id or serial number or what ever, search for the price from from your database based on the id. This way, if a user sends a forged id, there won't be any harm to you, the data is just not found, and if it is, it doesn't matter how a user have actually chosen a product.

Comment: Well yes, you can actually calculate e.g. a HMAC over the parameters and add that as final parameter. The secret key used for that can be stored server side only. Then you can always **detect** changes for this particular URL. However, that doesn't necessarily the complete system secure; I would try and avoid relying on any information from the client (and please use a service for payment details).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming, it is about [security.se].